# Como converter um objeto jQuery em html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá, eu estou tentando criar um botão de download depois que o conteúdo da página for apagado. Eu estou usando o jQuery para criar o botão, mas preciso do html para usar como parâmetro de "document.write()". Têm como transformar um objeto jQuery em uma string html?

```js
function criarBotaoDownload(){
    var botao = $("<a>");
    botao.attr("download", "download");
    botao.attr("href", enderecoDoArquivo);
    botao.text("Baixar!");

    //?????

    document.write(//Quero colocar o link aqui!);
}

criarBotaoDownload();
```

Eu pensei em colocar dentro de uma div e puxar o valor com ".innerHTML" mas me pareceu ser uma grande gambiarra então vim perguntar aqui.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você realmente não precisa fazer isso, muito menos utilizar o `document.write`; basta utilizar a função `append` do jQuery:

```js
function criarBotaoDownload(){
    var botao = $("<a>");
    botao.attr("download", "download");
    botao.attr("href", 'url');
    botao.text("Baixar!");

    $('body').append(botao);
}

criarBotaoDownload();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Olá Anderson, de fato não é necessário. Eu só queria saber se era possível transformar um objeto jQuery em html porquê nesse caso eu realmente gostaria de usar o ```document.write()``` isso é possível?

Comment: @WiltonRibeiro Mas o que justifica esse uso?

Comment: Eu estou criando um script para usar com o devtools do navegador. Esse script irá olhar para o código de um determinado site, reescrever e depois me apresentar o resultado apagando o conteúdo do site anterior.